# Solr numDocs Overflow

Tags: solr, lucene

We're running Solr to index large amounts of data and just ran into a very interesting problem to which I haven't been able to find any help anywhere.

It seems Solr is using a signed 32-bit integer to count the number of documents currently in the index. We just reached that number and our Solr statistics page show the following:

```
numDocs : -2116382092
maxDoc : -2114669444
```

Solr still seems to be able to index incoming data just fine but when we search we get a NegativeArraySizeException (see stacktrace below)

We assume that the error and the overflow are connected (a fair assumption I believe).
There is nothing in the Solr documentation and so far I haven't been able to find any relevant help on the subject. The solution to the problem is most likely to drop a chunk of the index to reduce the size below MAX_INT but we're not sure that'll work as Solr most likely has to perform a search in order to find the documents to delete.

**I guess this is not so much a question as it is stating the facts but I would like to know if anyone else has ever come across this issue and if so, how you solved it?**

```
 java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.apache.solr.search.DocSetCollector.<init>(DocSetHitCollector.java:47)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocSetNC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:627)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getPositiveDocSet(SolrIndexSearcher.java:563)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocSet(SolrIndexSearcher.java:592)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListNC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:903)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:884)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.search(SolrIndexSearcher.java:341)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.process(QueryComponent.java:182)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:195)
    at    org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:131)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1316)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:338)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at     org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at     org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Solr derives the value from `Lucene`. Lucene uses `int` as handles. So problem has more to do with Lucene than Solr. Just curious, you didn't do any kind of capacity planning, system/architecture design to see if it is ready for indexing billions of documents ?? Perhaps it will be helpful if you mention the version of Lucene/Solr that you are using.

Comment: I don't know if there is any way around this, but I would suggest you ask on the Solr user mailing list.

Comment: primitive ints in Java are 32bit signed, so the maximum value is 2,147,483,647. you have 2 billion documents indexed in Solr/Lucene? wow. i remember reading somewhere that you should not expect Lucene to handle more than a few million docs in a single index.

Comment: The index itself has been performing nicely up until now so actually keeping a 2 billion doc (small documents) index hasn't been a problem. That said, we didn't quite mean for it to grow this large. **We are running version 1.4.1.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have managed to solve the issue after a bit of pain.

**What we did and how we solved it**

First we ran CheckIndex to verify that all segments and the index it self was in good shape and hadn't gone corrupt. This also let us know that we had enough RAM to do some real work on our larger segments later. As epected, the result of CheckIndex was ok. **CheckIndex** is available in the Lucene library.

Step two was to split the index in two by segments (not in half).
In our case we had one huge segment consisting of about 1.7 billion documents, we simply isolated that segment from the source index and created two new indexes, one of only the large segment and one of the remaining 20 something segments we had.
To do this we used the **IndexSplitter**, also from the Lucene library.

Splitting the index requires Lucene 3.0.x and we only had Lucene 2.9.3 (bundled with Solr 1.4.1) installed. We downloaded a separate instance of Lucene 3.0.3 to get our hands on the IndexSplitter. 
The two new indexes created were incompatible with our Lucene version so we ended up having to upgrade Lucene in our Solr installation to 2.9.4 which can read 3.0.x indexes.

We then booted Solr pointing towards each of the new indexes, one at a time. This time the numDocs was below MAX_INT and we could run our delete statements.
After doing this on both the two new indexes we simply merged them together using the **IndexMerge** tool, also in Lucene library,  what was left and ended up with a healthy 1.5 billion doc index that will last us another couple of months :)
Lesson learned here is to run the delete queries before we hit the ceiling.

**A question to all Lucene experts:**

What actually happens when you continue to index after MAX_INT has been hit? Are we overwriting data? If yes, what data is most likely to be overwritten?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using distributed searching?

"If you have so many documents that you simply cannot fit them all on a single box for RAM or index size reasons, you can split an index into multiple pieces, called shards." Lucidworks

- http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/A+Quick+Overview
- http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Distributed+Search+with+Index+Sharding
- http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch

Comment: The system where we have this issue at the moment is a legacy system. We are rebuilding the infrastructure for Solr at the moment where we will have a sharded setup over several hardware nodes (and also internally on each physical machine). Unfortunately it wasn't an option to migrate the existing index to this new infrastructure so it doesn't help us right now.